# Can i access datacontext inside model in breeze and durandal?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal, hottowel

I want to create knockout computed function which will do ajax call with breeze method and retrieve all records based upon entity type as shown below.

```
standardResourceProperty.listItems = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            listObsevable = ko.observableArray();
            datacontext.getStandardResourcePropertyListItems(standardResourceProperty.id(),listObsevable);
            return listObsevable;
        },
        write: function (value) {

        }
    });
```

The function is written inside standardResourcePropertyInitializer which is initialized with

```
metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
        'StandardResourceProperty', function () { this.isPartial = false; }, standardResourcePropertyInitializer);
```

I want to have list when i iterate standard resource in ui with knockout for each .

However, **i am getting datacontext as undefined** . Even thought it is registered properly with durandal in the same file as

```
define(['config', 'durandal/system', 'services/logger', 'services/datacontext'],
function (config, system, logger,datacontext) {
```

My data context code looks like below

```
define([
'durandal/system',
'services/model',
'config',
'services/logger',
'services/breeze.partial-entities'],
function (system, model, config, logger, partialMapper) {

var datacontext = {
        getResources: getResources,
        cancelChanges: cancelChanges,
        saveChanges: saveChanges,
        getStandardResourceProperty: getStandardResourceProperty,
        getStandardResourcePropertyListItems: getStandardResourcePropertyListItems,
        getResourceProperty: getResourceProperty,
        createResource: createResource,
    };

    return datacontext;
});
```

Please let me know for any suggestion.

Comment: How does your datacontext service look like? It's possible that you aren't returning an object instance from it.

Comment: Nop that is not that case as in my viewmodels it is being retrieved properly. However, for the given case i want to construct my model by consuming datacontext. So i am not sure why is the same datacontext not working properly with model when it is working with viewmodel

Comment: @parth1729 Can you edit your post and add your data context code?

Comment: @CodingGorilla I have added sample code with some of the methods i am returning from the datacontext.js file

Comment: @parth1729 Are you able to verify (via debugger, or console.log) that `datacontext` is not undefined prior to creating your computed?

Comment: @CodingGorilla Yes i have checked putting console.log that datacontext is undefined even in start of the modelfunction and also in function where we have initialize all breeze entities with metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor(
            'Resource', function () { this.isPartial = false; }, resourceInitializer);

Comment: @parth1729 have you solved it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more investigation i have implemented server side query to return related objects(child objects ) and then created computed for accessing it with knockout binding in view.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution!
Create a new file called binding.js under services folder

```
define(['services/logger', 'services/datacontext'], function (logger, datacontext) {
    logger.log('about to do binding');
    YOUR KO CODE 
    datacontext.createTimeSlotWithValue({
                    description: 'descrizione da drop'
                });
                datacontext.saveChanges();
});
```

Add  ‘services\logger’ in sheel.js when you define it. This is cleaner